# Aplicar Junit a un metodo

Tags: java, depuración, junit, junit-5

Pretendo crear una prueba Junit para el siguiente método ingresar. Quiero crear una prueba para cantidad<0, me debería devolver un valor de 1 (iCodErr=1)

```html
public int ingresar(double cantidad)  {

        int iCodErr;
        
        if (cantidad < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("No se puede ingresar una cantidad negativa");
            iCodErr = 1;
        }
        else if (cantidad == -3)
        {
            System.out.println("Error detectable en pruebas de caja blanca");
            iCodErr = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            
            dSaldo = dSaldo + cantidad;
            iCodErr = 0;
        }     
        return iCodErr;
    }
```

La prueba que he diseñado es la siguiente:

```html
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CCuenta_Test_1 {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Test
    public void testIngresar() {
        
        CCuenta objCuenta = new CCuenta();   //creo instancia
        double resultado =  objCuenta.ingresar(-5.0); // para llamar al metodo ingresar
        //variable con el resultado esperado del metodo ingrear (1.0)
        double esperado = 1;  
        assert.assertEquals(esperado,resultado);    
    }
}
```

Pero eclipse me subraya en rojo la ultima línea y me dice:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to boolean
Alguien puede ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente:

```
assertEquals(esperado,resultado);
```

`assert` es un [keyword de Java independiente de JUnit](https://picodotdev.github.io/blog-bitix/2015/02/la-palabra-clave-assert-de-java-y-un-ejemplo/), aunque el significado está más o menos relacionado. No devuelve un valor, así que es una expresión *void* y no tiene métodos. Ése es el error que te indica.

Lo que haces con JUnit normalmente es un *import static* de *org.junit.Assert*

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

y eso hace que puedas invocar los métodos estáticos de *Assert* directamente, entre los que está el *assertEquals*. Si no hicieras el *import static*, tendrías que hacer (nota la A mayúscula, aquí referencias la clase):

```
Assert.assertEquals(esperado, resultado);
```